# Reading input from stdin

Tags: c, stream

I read user input from `stdin` in plain `C`. 
The problem is that I want a sane implementation that is robust to errors and restricts the user to a certain input and doesn't suck in terms of complexity. 
The function `get_strings()` reads input char by char as long there is no new line (`\n`), no `EOF` and all chars are passing the `isalpha()` test. But I want to keep spaces.

Some points that (I think) deserve special attention during the review:

  - I would love to get rid of the outer while loop which is basically testing wether the user just pressed Enter without any meaningful input.

  - Do I even need to use ferror()? fgetc already returns EOF when something did go wrong, but I will just stop reading from the stream instead of telling the user something went wrong.

  - It doesn't happen everytime but it happens: A \n stays in the stdin stream and the next time I want to get meaningful input fgetc() just gets skipped. It doesn't matter here, but it does when I am asking single character Yes/No questions. I can only get rid of this problem with a construct that clears out all previous things that are left in stdin. See the second codeblock for this.

So, am I handling this totally wrong? Are there better practices to embrace? It looks really clunky to me, and clunky is always bad.

```
/** @brief Contains the dictionary */
static char **strings = NULL;

/** @brief Helps with containing the dicionary */
static char *string;

/* Reads input char by char with fgetc() */
static char *get_strings() 
{
    char *string = NULL;
    char ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    while (string == NULL && ch != EOF) {
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(in_stream)) && ch != '\n') {
        if (ch != ' ' && isalpha((int)ch) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Only [a-z] is a valid input. | \t"
                                "| Input another or end with CTRL+D: ");
            continue;
        }
        string  = (char*) realloc(string, len+2);
        if (string == NULL) {
            bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc(3) failed");
        }
        string[len++] = toupper(ch);

        if (len >= MAX_DATA) {
            bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "Input too long\n");
        }
    }
    if (ferror(in_stream)) {
        bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error while reading from stream");
    }
    }

    if(string) {
        string[len] = '\0';
    } else {
        printf("\nFinished dictionary...\n");
    }
    printf("Added string: %s | Input another or end with CTRL+D: ", string); 
    return string;
}

/* Saves the returned strings from get_strings() in a linked list */
static void read_dict()
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; (string = get_strings()); ++index) {
        if (string[0] == '\0') continue; 
        strings = (char**) realloc(strings, (index+1)*sizeof(*strings));
        if (strings == NULL) {
            bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "realloc(3) failed");
        }
        strings[index] = string;
    }

    /* Take a note of how many entries we have yet. */
    dict_size = index;
}
```

Second CodeBlock with a more simple case:

```
while(1) {
    char tmp;
    printf("Please enter your guess [a-z]: ");
    guess = fgetc(stdin);
    /* Jump back to start of loop */  
    if (guess == '\n') {
        continue;
    }

    /* HERE IS THE CLEAR FOR STDIN
       This part really just eats all remaining \ns from the user,
       so that later inputs can start uninterrupted. Can I get rid of
       it in some better way? */
    while((tmp = getchar()) != '\n' && tmp != EOF);

    if(!isalpha(guess)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Enter a valid letter [a-z]!\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick note: prefer to use boolens from <stdbool.h> or defines rather than 1 and 0. It's more clear what you mean

Comment: @Zorgatone I half agree with you; always use `stdbool.h`, but don't try to roll your own bools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Architecture**

`stdin` is usually [line buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359).  So nothing is given to `fgetc()` until the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  OP code will give multiple error messages with input like "Hello 123".  Better to separate user input from input validation.  Read the line of user input with `fgets()` or some version of your own as `fgets()` does have some weaknesses.  *Then* validate the input.

```
char *input;
while ((input = my_gets()) != NULL) {
  if (valid_phrase(input)) {
    foo(input);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
  }
  free(input);
}
```

Concerning "I would love to get rid of the outer while loop".  That loop exists to silently consume `'\n'`.  If you want a loop to do that, just preceded inner loop with

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc()) == '\n')
  ;
ungetc(ch, stdin);
```

**`char ch`**

The `ch` is not the best type.  `fgetc()` returns typically 257 different values `[0-255]` and `EOF`.  To properly distinguish them, save the result in an `int`.

```
// bad
char ch;
..
while (string == NULL && ch != EOF) {    
while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(in_stream)) && ch != '\n') {

// better
int ch;
..
while (string == NULL && ch != EOF) {
  while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(in_stream)) && ch != '\n') {
```

Same for `char tmp;`

**`realloc()`**

Cast not need.
Modify for out of memory to free `string` - not needed if code will simply exits, yet good practice to put your toys (code's pointer) away.

```
// string  = (char*) realloc(string, len+2);
char * new_string  = realloc(string, len+2);
if (new_string == NULL) {
  free(string);
  bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "Out of memory");
}
string = new_string;
```

Good use of of `sizeof(*strings)` below.  Recommend simplification.

```
strings = (char**) realloc(strings, (index+1)*sizeof(*strings));
strings = realloc(strings, sizeof *strings * (index+1));
```

**`size_t len`**

Good use of `size_t` to represent an array size.  Curiously code does not do  the same with `int index;`.  Recommend `size_t index;`

**`is...()`**

With using `int ch`, no need for cast.  Since this is a logical test, recommend using `!` rather than arithmetic `== 0`.

```
// if (ch != ' ' && isalpha((int)ch) == 0) {
if (ch != ' ' && !isalpha(ch)) {
```

The following may be easier to understand - fewer negations.  (Style issue)

```
if (!(ch == ' ' || isalpha(ch))) {
```

**`ferror()`**

Nice check of `if (ferror(in_stream))`

**Variable names**

`string`, `strings` is as useful as calling an integer `integer`.  Maybe `phrase`, `dictionary` instead.

```
// OK
/** @brief Contains the dictionary */
static char **strings = NULL;

// Better
// comment not truly needed
static char **dictionary = NULL;
```

`get_strings()` is mis-named.  It sounds general, yet code restricts input to letters and space.  Maybe `get_words()`?

Comment: I feel like you did post the same answer twice?
Anyways, this is the answer I was looking for! I was totally focused on using fgetc sind fgets did'nt work in the start (Because of rogue \ns in stdin). This seems way better and I will incorporate this in my code. Thanks!

Comment: @Haini you know that in addition to accept, you can also upvote an answer if you liked it so much ;-)

Answer (score 2):

#### Bad realloc strategy

Currently, you call `realloc()` on every character you read.  This results in an \$O(n^2)\$ time to read a string, because every time you call `realloc()`, it may need to copy the current contents to the new buffer.  You should either just allocate a buffer of size `MAX_DATA` and then use `realloc` to shrink the allocation at the end, or change to a reallocation strategy where the reallocation size is increased by a multiplicative factor each time (such as 2x).

This also applies to your array of strings, where you do the same thing.

#### Strange indentation

Your indentation is strange because your nested `while` loop is on the same indentation level as the outer `while` loop.

#### Use fgets()?

I would personally use `fgets()` (or some other library function such as `readline()`) to read a string.  `fgets()` does pretty much what your loop does without all the handcoded logic.